# Identification of a strange skull

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology, ichthyology, bone

My father is a fisherman in the Baltic sea, and he has found this very strange skull. I would like to know to which animal it belonged. Can someone help identify it? [image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have more photos or anything to measure the scale. This picture is all I've got.

Comment: You've got a coarse black cloth with a weave in the back-ground. If you can find the cloth type, you can probably make an estimate of rough dimensions. I'd hazard a guess of about 30-40 cm across the widest part and similar top-to-bottom.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've manage to get rough estimate of the dimensions - around 30x25 cm.

Comment: @BassAstral if you edit that information into your question, more people will see the dimensions and you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I thought it might be a vertebral scute from a sea turtle, but apparently there are none in the baltic sea

Comment: @timeskull in Baltic you can't exclude anything because just recently there was walrus here who unfortunately died. Here has been several findings common monkfish, dolphins, whales and other usually not Baltic species who usually get lost their way or are brought by ships (smaller). Same way many years there was grey seal living in Black sea who was probably taken from Baltic sea as pup by some sailor and released there when it wasn't so cute anymore and started biting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this is a neurocranium of a tuna or a similar species (dorsal view on [this site](https://osteobase.mnhn.fr/region.php?lang=en&idStructure=12&idTaxon=30)).

I've also found a very similar picture of Atlantic blue tuna from USA, which seems to support that this is indeed a neurocranium.([source of the picture](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/6gvdh5/found_on_beach_ocean_in_ma_usa_iphone_5_for/)).

[image: Atlantic blue tuna's neurocranium]

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Can you add an inline image and supporting information of your ID? As of now it's more of a comment than an answer. Additional supportive evidence can consist of checking whether size measures and habitat correspond to your specimen, and whether the area of distribution of your ID matches where the specimen was found *etc.*

Comment: Thanks @AliceD! I've added an image and some more information, although I don't know how to specify all of the required information. My skills and knowledge in that regard are rather limited.

Comment: Great answer! You cannot know how happy I am that you posted an answer. I thought I was crazy for thinking it was a skull (based on the atlas bone and the sutures). Wish I could upvote this 10 times.

Comment: Just upvoted this 15 more times. :) Rarely is such a definitive answer provided so quickly to a mysterious object, much less from the OP themself. Very well done.